# Where can I find the class "org.terrier.realtime.memory.MemoryIndex" to import and use?

Tags: java, search, information-retrieval

I am following `Quickstart Guide: Integrating Search into your Application available` at Terrier Information Retrieval platform's website: [Terrier IR platform homepage](http://terrier.org/docs/current/quickstart-integratedsearch.html), using the following code, available at their webpage. The code uses `org.terrier.realtime.memory.MemoryIndex` but it is not available in the `terrier jar files`, which I have included in my project using `maven`.

I have checked both `Terrier` `5.1` and `5.0` but was unable to locate the `MemoryIndex class` and its constructor.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.terrier.indexing.Document;
import org.terrier.indexing.TaggedDocument;
import org.terrier.indexing.tokenisation.Tokeniser;
import org.terrier.querying.LocalManager;
import org.terrier.querying.Manager;
import org.terrier.querying.ManagerFactory;
import org.terrier.querying.ScoredDoc;
import org.terrier.querying.ScoredDocList;
import org.terrier.querying.SearchRequest;
import org.terrier.realtime.memory.MemoryIndex;
import org.terrier.utility.ApplicationSetup;
import org.terrier.utility.Files;


public class IndexingAndRetrievalExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Directory containing files to index
        String aDirectoryToIndex = "/my/directory/containing/files/";

    // Configure Terrier
            ApplicationSetup.setProperty("indexer.meta.forward.keys", "docno");
    ApplicationSetup.setProperty("indexer.meta.forward.keylens", "30");

    // Create a new Index
            MemoryIndex memIndex = new MemoryIndex();

    // For each file
            for (String filename : new File(aDirectoryToIndex).list() ) {

                    String fullPath = aDirectoryToIndex+filename;

        // Convert it to a Terrier Document
                    Document document = new TaggedDocument(Files.openFileReader(fullPath), new HashMap(), Tokeniser.getTokeniser());

        // Add a meaningful identifier
                    document.getAllProperties().put("docno", filename);

                    // index it
                    memIndex.indexDocument(document);
            }

            // Set up the querying process
            ApplicationSetup.setProperty("querying.processes", "terrierql:TerrierQLParser,"
            + "parsecontrols:TerrierQLToControls,"
            + "parseql:TerrierQLToMatchingQueryTerms,"
            + "matchopql:MatchingOpQLParser,"
            + "applypipeline:ApplyTermPipeline,"
            + "localmatching:LocalManager$ApplyLocalMatching,"
            + "filters:LocalManager$PostFilterProcess");

            // Enable the decorate enhancement
            ApplicationSetup.setProperty("querying.postfilters", "org.terrier.querying.SimpleDecorate");

            // Create a new manager run queries
            Manager queryingManager = ManagerFactory.from(memIndex.getIndexRef());

            // Create a search request
            SearchRequest srq = queryingManager.newSearchRequestFromQuery("search for document");

            // Specify the model to use when searching
            srq.setControl(SearchRequest.CONTROL_WMODEL, "BM25");

            // Enable querying processes
            srq.setControl("terrierql", "on");
            srq.setControl("parsecontrols", "on");
            srq.setControl("parseql", "on");
            srq.setControl("applypipeline", "on");
            srq.setControl("localmatching", "on");
            srq.setControl("filters", "on");

            // Enable post filters
            srq.setControl("decorate", "on");

            // Run the search
            queryingManager.runSearchRequest(srq);

            // Get the result set
            ScoredDocList results = srq.getResults();

            // Print the results
            System.out.println("The top "+results.size()+" of documents were returned");
            System.out.println("Document Ranking");
            for(ScoredDoc doc : results) {
                int docid = doc.getDocid();
                double score = doc.getScore();
                String docno = doc.getMetadata("docno")
                System.out.println("   Rank "+i+": "+docid+" "+docno+" "+score);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I identified the problem. The problem was with setting maven dependencies. Here, is how the problem can be solved by adding the following dependencies while building the maven project:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terrier</groupId>
    <artifactId>terrier-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terrier</groupId>
    <artifactId>terrier-realtime</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class `MemoryIndex.java` is a part of terrier-core version 4.4. More info: https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.terrier/terrier-core/4.4/source-code/org/terrier/realtime/memory/MemoryIndex.java

And their documentation seems to be out of date.

Comment: Thanks Asanka for help. I used the documentation for version 4.2, available at their site and found the code list there working....